# How do I use Vue to add actual html to my code?

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a simple deck editor using Vue and I want to have a list of cards which have an "Add" button on them.

When the button is clicked, I want the cards image and name to appear on a side bar. However concatenating to a "deck" variable returns a string literal.

```html
<div id = app> 
     <p v-on:click="addImg">
         {{ Images }}} 
     </p>
</div>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: {
      premium: true
    }
})

data() {
    return {
    images: ""
}

 methods: {
      addImg: function() {
          this.images += <img src="example text">
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering text, but appending html.

```html
<p v-on:click="addImg" v-html='images'></p>
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Adding element or component better to use array instead of string: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for